# How to upload recordings to Sound Cloud using ASP.NET and C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, audio, soundcloud, audio-recording

I have a website where people come and leave messages for admin using voice. I don't have much space on my web-server. So I want to upload the recorded audio tracks to sound cloud. I searched the internet but was unable to find any solution. So I want to ask is there any class library or tutorial available that teaches how to record sound on a website and upload it to Sound Cloud or any other service?

Comment: Did you find/look at the api yet? http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs

Comment: ya but they have solutions for php, ruby,python,JS. I want a straight solution like Facebook C# SDK for Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Soundcloud does not offer a C# API only Python, Ruby, PHP, Java, iOS and JavaScript, but others have wrapped them, I searched for nuget soundcloud and found one: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Ewk.SoundCloud.ApiLibrary/

Comment: Nice option. But I didn't find any details on how to use it on that site and not even on project's site. So, can you suggest me some tutorial on it if you know any?

Comment: No I don't know. But given it's a wrapper around the regular APIs, I'd just give it a go following the normal tutorials. The writer should have kept names similar. Just note they have gone for a fluent API, so it might be a bit different to use, but it just shouldn't be a million miles from any other soundcloud API.